# How create pay Chrome app with PayPal?

Tags: google-chrome, paypal, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

I see that you can make a pay packaged app with the Google Wallet API (for in the Chrome Web Store). https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/index#charging And also it is possible to create a custom pay service. So I want create an app that use PayPal as payment solution.

Any sample how to do this? A basic sample sample will be great.

Comment: Custom payment service means you implement custom payment in your app. That's why they suggest to use google wallet api, because it integrated well with google services. If you want to add custom payment option like paypal into your app, you will need to use paypal api todo so. https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/

Comment: nobody? need only basic sample
(why paypal -> because it doesn't need a credit card to signup)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the PayPal IPN system with PHP, the IPN system stores data into an SQL server.. [Here's a good sample](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/)

Answer (score 1):

There's a [PayPal API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/) you can use and [here's an express checkout example app (with code)](http://www.digitalgoodsexpresscheckout.com/PayPal/Articles/DigitalGoodsExpressCheckout/DigiGoodsEC.html).

Comment: look something in the good way... but is this possible for in a Chrome packaged app? Have you tried to create this in an app?

Comment: an other question, when i buy an 'widget' on that site. How can i check if the users buy it not again and again. Because i test it here, and see no links to a 'special' page...

Comment: @user1731468 Maybe you could add a variable which is set when the user buys the item and then check its value when the user is trying to make another purchase.

Comment: @user1731468 on the end it give me an 'api successfull popup'. How to change it to a full website. Example it go direct to www.google.com